# Read-only text field

Tags: cucumber, watir, readonly, textfield

I have an read-only text-field in my site. And I need to enter a date using cucumber and watir. But I can't set any value. Even passing the value of date with `value =` method I can't input any output. There is a JavaScript calendar.

I wrote:

```
browser.text_field(:name => "deal[start_date]").value = 'test'
```

it shows the following error:

```
Watir::Exception::ObjectReadOnlyException: Watir::Exception::ObjectReadOnlyException
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.1.7/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:252:in `assert_writable'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/watir-webdriver-0.1.7/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/text_field.rb:24:in `value='
    from (irb):10
```

Please help me, I am in a trouble.

Answer (score 2):

This goes along with what xboxer21 noted.  I found this code worked for me on a site that had a similar calendar widget.

Lets say you have an HTML form with input text fields that are set to readonly:

```
<form name="FindRange" method="post" action="FindRange.asp" onsubmit="return false">
 ...
 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tr>
  <td colspan="3" class="FieldLabel">
    <input type="text" name="FromDate" size="16" readonly="true" style="width:85px; background-color:#F8F6E7;">
  </td>
  <td>
     <input type="text" name="ToDate" size="16" readonly="true" style="width:85px; background-color:#F8F6E7;">
  </td>
 </tr>
 ...
</form>
```

Using code like '@ie.text(:name, "FromDate").set("3/23/2011")' in your Ruby Watir script would result in an error in Ruby stating the field was read-only.  But using the eval() method may allow you to use Javascript to set the read-only fields behind the scenes.

```
#Code above these lines instantiate the Watir object in @ie and navigate to the page   #containing the HTML form
#named 'FindRange'
@ie.document.parentWindow.eval("document.FindRange.FromDate.value = '3/23/2011'")
@ie.document.parentWindow.eval("document.FindRange.ToDate.value = '3/24/2011'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try executing the JavaScript itself.

```
browser.document.parentWindow.execScript("Date_JS_script('date')")
```

Comment: As Željko hints at, the correct approach here is to perform the same steps a user would, i.e. clicking the JS calendar. Only a very special kind of user would manually execute a piece of JavaScript to select the date. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, the text field is read only, as the error message says. That means it can not be changed. How would you change the value of the text field without Watir? Can you provide link to the page or relevant HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to enter a date in a read only text field, The JS calendar script used was http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/

There is a small icon next to the date field which displays the calendar widget upon clicking it.

```
browser.image(:id,"datewidget-trigger").click # Will display the Calendar 
browser.send_keys("{ENTER}") # Will select current date
```

If you want to select a future date or previous date

```
browser.send_keys("{LEFT}")
browser.send_keys("{RIGHT}")
```

This has been tested using IE only.